# Button and text label in vue are not clickable

Tags: css, json, vue.js

So I have created a registration page in vue and when I want to type something in the box or click the register/login button it wont do anything but if I hit TAB and write my password and then hit TAB and press ENTER it will work.

This is the code:

```
<div class="login-box">
  <div v-if="pageMethod == 'login'">
    <h1 class="display-4">Authentication</h1>
    <p class="lead small">You are registered on this server. Insert your account's password to proceed with the authentication.</p>
  </div>
  <div v-if="pageMethod == 'register'">
    <h1 class="display-4">Registration</h1>
    <p class="lead small">You are not registered on this server. Insert your account's password to proceed with the reegistration.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="input-group">
    <input v-model="password" :type="showPassword == true ? 'text' : 'password'" class="form-control"
      placeholder="Password">
    <div @click="showPassword = !showPassword" class="input-group-prepend">
      <span class="input-group-text">
        <i :class="showPassword != true ? 'fas fa-eye-slash' : 'fas fa-eye'"></i>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button v-if="pageMethod == 'login'" @click="sendAuth(true)" class="btn btn-primary mt-3">Login</button>
  <button v-if="pageMethod == 'register'" @click="sendAuth(false)" class="btn btn-primary mt-3">Register</button>
</div>
```

And this is the login-box css part:

```
.login-box {
text-align: center;
z-index: 1;
height: 100%;
width: 400px;
position: absolute;
right: 0px;
top: 0px;
display: flex;
background-color: rgba($card-bg, 0.8);
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
padding: 10px 15px;
h1 {
  font-family: 'HouseScript';
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it. There was a logo that was hovering over the textlabel and button. I had to add pointer-events: none; in the css part of the logo. Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [tabIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex) and also, listen for `Enter` [@keyup.enter](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Key-Modifiers) :

```html
<input v-model="password" :type="showPassword == true ? 'text' : 'password'" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" tabindex="0">
...
<button v-if="pageMethod == 'login'" @click="sendAuth(true)" class="btn btn-primary mt-3" tabindex="1" @keyup.enter="sendAuth(true)">Login</button>
<button v-if="pageMethod == 'register'" @click="sendAuth(false)" class="btn btn-primary mt-3" tabindex="2" @keyup.enter="sendAuth(false)">Register</button>
```

Comment: I have replaced what you told me but now the textbox is clickable in a small portion and the button is still not clickable.

Comment: https://codepen.io/brospresident/pen/vYOvqaZ

I couldnt make it look like it should on that website. It was the first time I worked with it.

Comment: It's not working, it is not enough to just paste code there, you need to plug in Vue and other things. Probably you have some CSS issue thats why only small portion is clickable

Comment: https://pastebin.com/gvMq5YdU This is my css part. I already put the part with login box in the first post but maybe u can see something else having the entire file

Comment: I fixed it. There was a logo that was hovering over the textlabel and button. I had to add pointer-events: none; in the css part of the logo. Thanks for your suggestions.